# How to select using sqlalchemy api with where clauses multiple filters?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, where-clause

I am trying to write a generic method that should accept filter dictionary as key values pair and using sqlalchemy create select statement supporting multiple where clauses.

```
def _get_selected_field_value(self, table, fields, col_value=None):
    """Performs select Operation and gets the value of field.

    Arguments:
        table (sqlalchemy.Table) : table to select data from.
        fields (list) : fields whose value to retrieve.
        col_value (dict) : where column of table has value.
    """
    stmt = db.select(fields).where(tuple_(*list(col_value.keys())).in_(list(col_value.values())))
```

but this is turning out to be

```
(Pdb) str(stmt)
'SELECT host.name \nFROM host \nWHERE (:param_1) IN ((:param_2))'
```

That doesn't look right!

So for a table that looks like this:

```
+----+-----------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------+
| id | name            | user         | ip_address    | mac_address       |
+----+-----------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------+
|  1 | DietPi          | root         | 192.168.0.151 | bx:2x:ex:bx:9x:6x |
+----+-----------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

I want

```
MariaDB [lan]> SELECT host.name from host WHERE host.user='root' and host.ip_address='192.168.0.151' ;
+--------+
| name   |
+--------+
| DietPi |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
stmt = db.select(fields).where(and_(*[column == value for column, value in col_value.items()]))
```

Comment: I got it working just changed to `stmt = db.select(fields).where(and_(*[getattr(table.columns, column) == value for column, value in col_value.items()]))
`